# Django Rest Framework - unable to add 'url' to HyperlinkedModelSerializer fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Edit: after some tinkering, I realized it's because the app URLs are namespace. URLS from the root app:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('boardcanvas.urls', namespace="boards"))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I guess the question now becomes... how do I correctly use namespace'd URLs?

I have what feels likes a stupid simple question, but the docs don't seem to address my issue at all. I'm using django-rest-framework as a backend for a react app, so I want the model list view to also include the url to the details view, so my view set looks like this:

```py
from ..models import BoardModel
from ..serializers import BoardSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class BoardViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BoardModel.objects.all().order_by('file_name')
    serializer_class = BoardSerializer
```

and the serializer looks like this:

```py
from .models import BoardModel
from rest_framework import serializers

class BoardSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BoardModel
        fields = ['url', 'slug', 'file', 'processed_file', 'file_name', 'keypoints']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'},
        }
```

and for good measure, the model:

```py
from django.db import models

from .validators import validate_img_ext, validate_keypoints_schema

def validate_file(v):
    validate_img_ext(v, [ '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg' ])

# Create your models here.
class BoardModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file])
    file_name: 'models.CharField' = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=75)
    processed_file = models.FileField(blank=True, validators=[validate_file])
    keypoints: 'models.JSONField' = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, validators=[validate_keypoints_schema])
    slug: 'models.SlugField' = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

and URLs with router:

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import board

app_name = 'boardcanvas'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'boards', board.BoardViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I know the routes are loading correctly, because I can see the `boardmodel-detail` route listed on the django error page:

[image]

With this configuration, I can start he API and see my boards endpoint, but as soon as I try and access the list view, I get this error:

`Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "boardmodel-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the 'lookup_field' attribute on this field`

which doesn't make any sense because I know the `slug` field exists and the route is there. And further, this is the only model I've even defined in this project, so I'm not sure what it's talking about when it says "relationship." I thought maybe if I removed the slug field it would work, but it doesn't. Same error. If I remove the `url` field from the serializer, everything loads just fine.